# Flow Component to display list of Account records in a screen Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, screen-flow, flow-screen-component

I'm calling an apex class from a screen flow that would return me list of account records. I want to display this list of records and be able to select those records individually in screen flow. Is there a screen flow component that I can use to accomplish this? Based on the records that I selected I want to create records in a related object later in the flow.Any suggestions on this please.

Answer (score 1):

To display records, there are two options that come to mind.

1. Use the standard [Record Choice Set](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_resources_recordchoice.htm&type=5) component. This limits you to only displaying a specific field from the record and doesn't work well when you need it to be formatted or additional fields displayed.
2. Use the Unofficial Salesforce [Datatable](https://unofficialsf.com/datatable-lightning-web-component-for-flow-screens-2/) component. This component is much more flexible and lets you display data in columns.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. All my accounts are stored in a collection variable that is returned by my apex class. If I select record choice set , I would need to get records from object based on filter condition. How can I use my record collection variable to show as list of records and be able to select them using checkbox.  Any suggestions would help

Comment: @SudhirBalijepalli Did you get your answer ?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the datatable component if the record choice set doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, there is a data table (beta) in screen flows that does this. [image: data table beta]